# Creating a gallery within a screen window?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm looking to create a simple UI to display the results of a project I've been working on. The simple display (upon which I'm hoping to build) is a splash screen which leads to gallery from which you can browse a number of .png files (graphs).

I'm looking to put this in my second screen (which at the moment is made up of two buttons.) I'm not looking for a complete solution from anybody, but some guidance would be appreciated. The idea would be that the second screen is linked to the directory containing the images, which can then be cycled through.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Create both screens. Please note the root.manager.current: this is how
# you can control the ScreenManager from kv. Each screen has by default a
# property manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'collage.png'

    BoxLayout:
        padding: [100, 100, 100, 100]


        Button:
            text: 'Go to Gallery'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.25
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.2}



<GalleryScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GalleryScreen(Screen):
    pass

# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(GalleryScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
         return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
     TestApp().run()
```

New to kivy, and under time constraints, which may explain the broad question, any help is appreciated.